# PDO last insert id Alternative?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am moving data from one table to another via a `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2` query. The data being moved contains information about employees (first name, last name...etc) as well as the path to that employee's resume. I'm now trying to split that information up into two different tables, one table for the employee info, and one table for the document (resume) info, linking the two by putting the employee ID in the document table. Both the employee ID and the document ID will be auto incremented PK values.

I understand that I can put these queries into a for loop and move one row at a time, grabbing the `last insert id` of the employee table before adding the document info to the document table in order to link the two. I am curious if there is a way to do this in one query, being able to take multiple rows from the original table, split up the info to be inserted into two new/different tables and and use the auto-generated id in the employee table as a value in the document table....hope this makes sense!

Comment: So, do you want to make insertions on two different tables with one single query? Why?

Comment: nope. insert_id() operates on the **LAST** individual insert operation performed by a particular database connection. There is no provision for capturing multiple IDs, or a per-table insert "log".

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to do, in hopes that it will be more efficient that moving one row at a time because there will be cases when I have to move thousands of rows, maybe even tens of thousands

Comment: @MarcB thats what I was afraid of....will I see significant losses in performance by moving one row at a time and essentially doing two more queries per row (one insert for emp data, grab last insert id, then insert doc data)? As opposed to the original insert into select * from format

Comment: no way to answer properly, you'd have to benchmark either way. but unless your tables are so incredibly huge that the db can't keep even the indexes in ram-based cache, then you're going to have crappy performance no matter which way you do it.

Comment: If this is something you're only going to be doing once, why is performance that critical? Loop through the rows and process the data as you see fit ... what are you looking to gain by making a one-time process more efficient?

Comment: Speed here is not an issue.Accuracy is.Create temp tables with a sample and ensure JOINs compare with origonal table.

Comment: What is the primary key on your current table that you want to split? Does every single row in it has resume column filled (meaning not null)?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM table` at the lowest level does that row by row, but doesn't expose useful information (last_insert_id). It's obvious you *need* the row-by-row approach since you depend on the generated auto_incremented id. If you're worried about performance - use transactional engine and commit every 1000 queries in a batch. It'll be quick enough, and you'll have the required accuracy as well.

Comment: @N.B. thanks that was the type of answer I was looking for, and is similar to what I have already. I was just curious if there was a more elegant way to do achieve this, without having to grab last_insert_id between each insert....perhaps some special mySQL syntax that i didnt know about lol

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I get this wrong but do you want to execute this query once with your current DB Tables?
And I guess both tables have the same amount of rows(and in order of each other)?

If you split those up you will get:

Employee table for example:

```
 - employee_id(auto_increment)
 - employee_firstname
 - employee_lastname
 - employee_document_id
 - +whatever you want etc
```

Document table for example:

```
 - document_id(auto_increment)
 - document_name
 - document_path
 - document_employee_id
 - +whatever you want etc.
```

If this is what you mean, than I think the following would work:

1: Setup PDO(The editor didn't work for me that's why ">")

```
    <?php

    $config['db'] = array(
        'host' => 'host',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'dbname' => 'dbname'
    );

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);

    ?>
```

---

2: Setup insert queries

---

```
<?php
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM table1"; 
//$db is PDO example name
$select_all = $db->prepare($select_query);
$select_all->execute();
$count = $select_all->rowCount();
for(var i = 0; i =< $count; ++i) { 
    $insert_query1 = "INSERT INTO table1 (employee_firstname,
    employee_lastname, employee_document_id)
    VALUES(employee_firstnameValue, employee_lastnameValue,'"i"'";

    $insert_query2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (document_name, document_path,
    employee_id) VALUES(document_nameValue, document_pathValue, '"i"')"

    $insert_table1 = $db->prepare($insert_query1);
    $insert_table1->execute()

    $insert_table2 = $db->prepare($insert_query2);
    $insert_table2->execute()
}
?>
```

I think the above will work because you get an auto_increment starting at 1, en de ++i will occur every time. So the employee_document_id and the document_employee_id will both get ++i(which is 1) just like the auto_increment is(also 1)

But maybe this is to much thought.. Or not going to work in your model

Side notes:

- Working with parameters is recommended in the query.
- This is just a loose describing method which came up in my mind(maybe you can pick something up from here..)

**EDIT: Another solution is to use a query like "SELECT MAX", but this is unsafe.**

Comment: There seems to be a few syntax errors. I think you've got the right idea, but I would recommend fixing the code.

Comment: Yeah I already thought that, this was an idea I quickly wrote in my mind and wrote on paper. I don't know the exact situation of the OP, this was just a mere thought. Thanks Dave Chen for you comment!

Comment: this is a great response, and is very similar to what I have already, but unfortunately not what I was looking for.....+1 for the effort tho.